# Why doesn't this small HTML/CSS snippet produce the expected results in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, cross-browser

You can save the code below and try it out.

In **firefox**,it's full browser grey,but in **IE**(IE7 to be exact),it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style text="text/css">
.overlay {  
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1000;
    background-color:grey;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div class="overlay"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE doesn't recognize the CSS color name `grey`. Try using a hex color, e.g., `#ccc`, and it will work. Alternatively, using `gray` (with an 'a', not an 'e') also works.

Note that this is standards-compliant, because W3C doesn't say anything about supporting alternate spellings of `gray`, and `gray` is indeed the color name [according to the spec for CSS3](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-color/#colorunits).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your style defs:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

On IE, `body` doesn't extend the full height of the viewport by default, and your overlay's container is `body`, so...

**Edit** Just tried it, and yours worked without the above, must be because body is statically positioned. Anyway, John Feminella figured it out; see his answer.